# Volley ImageLoader reloading loaded images on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, image-loading

I am using the following code to load images from server in a RecyclerView:

```
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(image_url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.title_img, R.drawable.reads, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.title_img.setImageUrl(image_url, imageLoader);
```

The problem is that when i scroll up again, the loaded images are reloaded.. How to avoid this...

Answer (score 0):

You should cache image in your device to prevent load image again.

Create a class named LruBitmapCache.java and add the following code. This class takes care of caching network images on disk.

LruBitmapCache.java

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

create class named AppController.java and paste the following content. This is a singleton class which initializes global instances of required classes. All the objects related to volley are initialized here:

```
import YourPakageName.LruBitmapCache;
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            getLruBitmapCache();
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
        }

        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
        if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
            mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
        return this.mLruBitmapCache;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Now open your AndroidManifest.xml file and add Application.java class in  tag:

```
<application
    android:name="YourPakageName.app.AppController"> ....</application>
```

After it go to your adapter and add following codes:

```
    private Context context;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = 
YourPakageName.AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        private RequestQueue queue;
        private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> imageCache;
```

and:

```
    public MyCustommAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<YourModel> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.postList = objects;
            final int maxMemory = (int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() /1024);
            final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 5;
            imageCache = new LruCache<Integer, Bitmap>(cacheSize);

            queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}
```

Now you can simply get url image and show it in list view:

```
 imageLoader.get(image_url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        // load image into imageview
                        holder.title_img.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why do we need to write all these in volley. Volley should rather provide built-in functions to do this.. Anyway will try ur code once if i get time.. Ryt now i m trying Picasso Library...

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation suggests that when a need to write the **LruBitmapCache.java** arrives, the heart of memory caching for images is in the following code snippet:

```
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
```

The **Android** [Caching Bitmap **documentation**](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) **specifically states**:

Note: In this example, one eighth of the application memory is allocated for our cache. On a normal/hdpi device this is a minimum of around 4MB (32/8). A full screen GridView filled with images on a device with 800x480 resolution would use around 1.5MB (800*480*4 bytes), so this would cache a minimum of around 2.5 pages of images in memory.

I have made a little experiment like what Khaled Rostampour suggested:

```
maxMemory / 5;
```

But setting the maxMemory to a lower number is better for a smooth experience just like the Facebook app experience.

I have made a basic test with this [Facebook-like app](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/), a good tutorial to follow on Volley which implements what Khalid has suggested, but I had trouble scrolling back and forth trying to achieve the ideal smoothness when maxMemory / 8 or even with maxMemory / 3.

I finally made a choice to set:

```
maxMemory / 2;
```

And guess what, the experience mimics the smoothness of the Facebook app (even much better).

So, depending on your need, you can appropriate how much memory you would allocate for your image caching routine within portions of your application.

The final determinant to consider in building an app just like the example I've referenced is the **user experience factor**. Its my 3rd week in android development, I realize that developers need to balance performance with the user experience, I found out that this is a good design pattern to keep in mind, which I believe, even proven applications that we often use pretty much does the same.

Answer (score -1):

The images will not reload from URL, but from cache. The recyclerview keep the images in memory and "recycle" the views for saving memory. If you don't want to recycle the views you need to use, for example, a ListView instead of RecyclerView.

Comment: If Cached Images Reused then there shud not be a lag. Moreover the images shud reappear by any means  when i disconnect the internet in the middle. But none of these is the case...

Comment: Even listview does recycling of views!

Comment: Normal listview not recycle the views, the Recycler View is an extension of the ListView that expose to you onBindViewHolder and this method create or recycle the views.